# How to implement list view having width less than window?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile. I want to implement list view as show in this image .Can you suggest me best way to implement that this list view which (width is less than than window width)?

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bNJt5/

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header" style="background: green;">
            <h1>Wbservice</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <!--pop up screen-->
    <div data-role="popup" id="webservice" data-close-btn="none">
        <div data-role="header" style="background: green;">
             <h1>Wbservice new/edit</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <input name="webserviceName" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Name the web Service" />
            <input name="Address" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Address of webservice" />
            <div class="tooltip_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div class="customFooter" data-role="footer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" id="Test" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" />
         <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Comment: override `.ui-listview` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EP6ws/

Comment: But it is not looking as in pic.Actually I think I need to add css

Comment: Omar can you help me in this making only one row

Comment: Secondly I want to add correct and cross button on my pop up screen , is this button available in jquerry mobile

Comment: there is same back and close button on header is there any button availavle on jquerry mobile

Comment: you can add close button this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bNJt5/